# Python SciPy FFT function - Input?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I am currently writing some code which is supposed to perform FFT on a set of data. I have a python list of points and I can easily create a time list. When I run fft(datalist), I get the 'TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable' error. I think (but please correct me) the issue is that the list is one dimension and they have no attachment to time at all by using that one line of code above. My question is, do I have to input a two dimensional array with time and data points? or am I completely wrong and have to rethink? 
Thanks, Mike
Edit - forgot to add some code. The t=time. Could it be because the number of entries in the array isnt equal to 2^n where N is an integer?

```
sample_rate=10.00
t=r_[0:191.6:1/sample_rate]
S = fft([mylist])
print S
```

Comment: Looks like you've accidentally overwritten `fft` with an array.  What does `print fft` give?

Comment: I don't see how that can be.  What does `print type(fft), repr(fft)` give?

Comment: Ill add my code up top - I appreciate the help so much!

Comment: Also didnt fully read your comment - thought you were referring to the fft results. print fft gives [ 10.6 +0.00000000e+00j   0.1 +3.29089653e+00j  -2.0 +0.00000000e+00j
  -0.2 +1.77635684e-15j  -2.0 +0.00000000e+00j   0.1 -3.29089653e+00j]

Comment: Had a trawl through my code and had some stuff earlier in the page I forgot to comment - thanks for the help. Still struggling with the input for fft though?

Answer (score 0):

The Numpy and SciPy fft functions are looking to have numpy arrays as input, not native python lists. Also they work just fine with lengths that are not powers of two. You probably just need to cast your list as an array before passing it to the fft.

From your example code above try:

```
from numpy.fftpack import fft
from numpy import array

""" However you generate your list goes here """

S = fft(array([mylist]))
```